# how to validate the registration form using java servlet

Tags: mysql

Please help me . how to validate the form using servlet. i did everything servlet but it won't work anything. My concept is if any filed is null/empty mean it redirect to registration form otherwise it will be updated in database

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="##09874##">
        <form method="post" action="insertData">  
            Employee id <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br><br>
            Password   <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br><br>
            Confirm Password   <input type="password" name="cpassword" value=""><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The input that you want to be must fill, mark with required attribute in html. then user will not be able to submit form without filling that inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Unknow

Answer (score -1):

use request.getParameter in servlet and then make if else condition.and use request.requestdispatcher.to verify user details use jsp and if the dttails is correct requestdispatcher will send to correct jsp and if the details is empty or wrong the you can send it to correct jsp...Im just trying to help im new in Java too.
Here is a example:

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

```
response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

String n=request.getParameter("username");  
String p=request.getParameter("userpass");  

if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
    rd.forward(request,response);  
}  
else{  
    out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
    rd.include(request,response);  
}  

out.close();  
}
```

Comment: but i am trying to insert the values in database (new user should be register registration form (username and password). if user name/password is null or empty mean it won't insert into database and redirect page and throws the exception username/password should not null/empty.